# what's the theoretical definition of a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, logic, category-theory, set-theory

I'd like to see, from the foundations point of view, what are called functions in Haskell.

See, categorically, there are "things" that compose associatively, with an identity function, and that would be enough, theoretically.

But everyone tries to convince me that this is not how functions are defined. A function is defined (they say) as a set of pairs of elements from two sets (domain and codoman), satisfying certain conditions. Meaning that a function is just a set. That you cannot define a function on something that is not a set.

If we apply this approach to Haskell, what I see is that `Hask` category is just a subcategory of `Sets`, which, to me, looks weird.

I'd rather extend the notion of function to apply to what we have in Haskell.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448563/whats-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-functor-in-haskell-only-definiti) in the comments this issue is tangentially touched, but not very deep. I'd like to hear a clear statement, like "but actually they are all sets", or "no, we have nothing to do with set theory".

Any ideas? Considerations?

Comment: Well, functions are one example (but definitely not the only example) of the things you describe from category theory. Also, unless I'm misunderstanding, this question seems to be mainly about the difference between sets and types (if so, this would be a good thing to search for, if you're looking for things to research related to this)?

Answer (score 9):

This is a very complex topic. In order to keep it simple and manageable, we often cut corners and often "lie".

Haskell, like all programming languages, has its own syntax and evaluation rules (*operational semantics*). However, thinking about a programming language only in operational terms can be quite limiting and cumbersome. When we call a `factorial` function we do not care about how it is implemented, or the exact number of evaluation steps it takes to provide its result.

To overcome this *denotational semantics* was proposed, where syntax is interpreted, piece by piece, in some "mathematical" model. It is possible that many different programs (syntactic expressions) map to the same interpretation (the "semantics").

As far as I know, a denotational semantics for the whole Haskell language was never defined. There are, though, models for Haskell fragments. These models usually are categories.

Here are a few examples.

If we (greatly!) restrict Haskell to a terminating, simply-typed core, then all we need is a (bi-)Cartesian closed category, and the category of sets suffices, with its products, coproducts and exponentials.

However, Haskell is not terminating, and has general recursion, so we need fixed points. Usually this is solved by moving to the category of complete partial orders (usually one between omega-CPO or DCPO).

Then we need type-level fixed points, so we need to consider a category with initial F-algebras (at least for well-behaved functors F). This severely makes things more complex.

We have not added polymorphism, yet! This is particularly tricky since Reynolds proved that polymorphism can not be naively modeled by sets ("polymorphism is not set-theoretic" is the main reference paper). So we now have PER models and Coherent models (both being categories) as some attempts to provide semantics to polymorphism.

Then we need type classes, GADTs, higher ranks, higher kinds, ...

In practice, we do not need this level of complexity. When programming, we usually deal with a limited amount of features, so we "lie" to ourselves and often pretend everything works like a set, or close enough. Then we add complexity back if really needed.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is a great description of the problem.
Still, I was not talking about modeling the theory, whether using denotational or operational semantics; either way, sets are not exactly a good idea... but as you hint, we can delimit our operations. I was talking about a proper theory; and is seems like F\omega may be good enough - as an idealized theory, of course.